# Get Php variable value from while loop into a javaScript

Tags: php

I have a Ajax function that connects to database to fetch "**ROWS**" of info. This is achieved using while..Fine..

I want the value of the while loop to be assigned to a radio button.

When I click each radio button, I want it to display the value that was assigned to it.
    i.e.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
   $mn = $row['mn'];
   echo $mn . "<td onclick = \"vote()\">
   <input type = \"radio\" id = \"voteCan\" value = \"$mn\">
   </td> 
   </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

The above query displays multiple results.

I have a JavaScript function to be fired when user clicks any of the radio button, but the JavaScript function is getting only the value of the first row. It's not getting the other rows.

Please any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try putting the onClick on the input instead of the td. Also, show your `vote()` function.

Comment: Ok, I did that not working still. Below is my vote().                                      <script>                                                                                            function vote(){
 voteFor = document.getElementById('voteCan').value;
   alert(voteFor);
 }
</script>

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
   $mn = $row['mn'];
   echo $mn . "<td onclick = \"vote(this)\">
   <input type = \"radio\" id = \"voteCan\" value = \"$mn\">
   </td> 
   </tr>";
  }
 echo "</table>";


<script>
function vote(e){
 var val = $(this).val();
 alert(val);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I got undefined as response.

Comment: var val = $(this).val(); alert (val);